# Given a paragraph of text, how to get everything from the start to the last whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a block of text like so:

```
"Hello world this is http://yahoo.com "
```

On keypress I'm looking at the text for links. I don't want to look for links in text while the user is still typing, example:

```
"Hello world this is http://yahoo.co"
```

How can I get everything in the text var starting from the left, 0, all the way to the last white space, meaning I don't get a url while the user is typing it?

Thanks

**UPDATED**

Typing `Hello world this is http://yahoo.com` should return `Hello world this is http://yahoo.com`

Typing `Hello world this is http://yahoo.co` should return `Hello world this is`

Comment: You could use the onblur event so that to look for link when the user finish typing the text.

Comment: thx but that won't due, I need it while the user is typing

Comment: Are you assuming that a user would always enter a space at the end of their text, or would they actually type "Hello world this is http://yahoo.com" <- no space

Comment: is the user necessarily going to put a space every time right after they put the link? you might want to rethink this whole idea in terms of user expereience

Comment: I will have a linkSearch func, that will trigger for text before a space, and also on paste, to get links that possibly won't have a trailing space. Thoughts?

Comment: You could also check the field onBlur, that way you'd find the links without an ending space.

Comment: Let the keypress event check for a link each time user press the key in behind the scene and if your linkSearch function found a valid url you could show some result as you want..

Comment: @DipuRaj that would result in searching for yahoo.co and not yahoo.com - which is why I posted this question...

Comment: mmm well that seems very strict validation, even 2 letter is valid like yahoo.in but not yahoo.co so you should improve your linkSearch function to be verify if the link exist, like using jquery load, if more focus to validation rather than performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods:

First, a regular expression:

```
var str    = "Hello world this is http://yahoo.co",
    expr   = /(.+\s).*$/
    result = str.match( expr )
;

console.log( result );
// => ["Hello world this is http://yahoo.co", "Hello world this is "]

console.log( result[1] );
// => "Hello world this is "
```

Second, [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
var str     = "Hello world this is http://yahoo.co",
    lastIdx = str.lastIndexOf( ' ' )
    result  = str.substr( 0, lastIdx + 1 )
;

console.log( result );
// => "Hello world this is "
```

This latter only works with spaces, however, as `lastIndexOf` doesn't take a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks but if I typed "Hello world this is http://yahoo.com " with a trailing space the link isn't being returned.

Comment: Thanks I tried the second but still not working. when I type "Hello World this is yahoo.com " that space after the .com should results in "Hello World this is yahoo.com" being returned. right?

Comment: I can only debug code I can see. Perhaps post the complete code you're using? When I use the code above with `var str = "Hello World this is yahoo.com ";` it returns `Hello World this is yahoo.com `. That seems correct per your question and comment.